# How can I monitor the memory status on an EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I found there is an memory leak in my instance,

But i couldn't find out the root cause,

How could I track the memory usage footprint on EC2 instance on Ubuntu system.

Comment: have you tried Newrelic yet?

Answer (score 3):

NewRelic is a good option. You can also install [this script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts-perl.html) on your server to send memory usage statistics to Amazon CloudWatch.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on your budget and level of details you want to get. It is recommended to start using free solution that can show the process's memory consumption over period of time, like [Newrelic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/servers/new-relic-servers-linux/getting-started/new-relic-servers-linux).

Answer (score 1):

I had a good experience with [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com) I collect a series of default metrics on the box and you can add your own both application and machine level. It's free for up to 5 servers. The agent is open source. The metrics collection library is statsd compatible.